# Is it better to use POCO objects or detached EntityFramework object to expose database via WCF?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, automapper, poco, t4

I created a `WCF service` in charge of exposing my database's data since I don't want the database to be directly accessed by my application (for security reasons) and i need to be able to share data with third-party applications.

My solution is structured this way: `WPF application` -> `WCFService library` -> `DataAccessLayer library`. (Arrows define assembly dependencies 'depends on')

To implement the `WCF service` I considered to simply return `detached EntityFramework objects` from the service BUT it forces the main application to have a dependency on the DataAccessLayer library.

The only way i can get around that is generating `POCO objects` and use them to send them over the wire, but now i have to map values back and forth `EntityFramework.`

At the moment i'm generating `POCO`s dynamically via a `T4 template` and I'm using `AutoMapper` to map values back and forth `EntityFramework`.

The Wcf service will just have to implement the repository pattern to expose data.

Is this a good solution? Are there any other option? 
Is there any shortcoming i should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your constraints, I would have to agree with this solution.

I created an almost identical solution, although our motivations were slightly different. Our client was Delphi Win32, and at the time didn't have good support for JSON, so we had to use SOAP.

The client also didn't support nullable primitives, so the POCOs removed all unsupported types, and performed other changes to ensure interoperability, then we used Automapper custom mappings to handle the two way conversions.

All the WCF services (contracts and implementations) where also generated by T4 templates, using a generic repository. With T4 templates, I was able to generate a separate WCF service per table for CRUD operations, and then manually created WCF services that were business specific.

Finally, I was also able to used T4 templates to generate the Delphi repositories that interacted with the SOAP services.

**Or**

You could just as easily move the POCOs (and code generation) to a separate project, change your DataAccessLayer library to reference the POCOs library and only contain the Db context made up of DbSets of your POCOs, and Data access logic but no entities (which are now POCOs). Your clients will not need to have a dependency on the DataAccessLayer library.

So... a good solution, depending on your constraints.